# Tableau - Connection Bad Status

Tags: tableau-api

have you ever seen Tableau Error code ?

`[Amazon][Amazon Redshift] (50) The connection has timed out, please reconnect. Current connection status is: [SQLState 08S01] CONNECTION_BAD`

could you give a solution for me ?

Comment: This could be related to requiring SSL. [Here](https://community.tableau.com/thread/236807) is a post in the Tableau community forums where someone has the same error id but a different error message.